# String manipulation/Handling in Lua, Rotation of words in a string

Tags: string, lua, concatenation, lua-table

I am trying to implement a function to rotate a string in Lua, something like this:
rotatedString = string.rotate(originalStringValue, lengthOfRotation, directionOfRotation)

For example, my input string = "Rotate and manipulate string"
And, I expect the function to give me output strings as follows (based on length of rotation and direction of rotation):
Output string example 1 : "string manipulate and Rotate"

Comment: You mean rotation of *words* in a string?

Comment: What is `lengthOfRotation` in your example?

Comment: What is the difference between rotating n left and -n right?

Comment: Yes, I mean rotation of words in a string...length of rotation is something like rotate 1 word, 2 words etc...in a certain direction...so, lengthOfRotation can be customized

Comment: rotating n-left and n-right is the same...only difference is the direction of rotation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
local teststr = "hello lua world. wassup there!"

local rotator = function(inpstr)

    local words = {}
    for i in string.gmatch(inpstr, "%S+") do
        words[#words+1] = i
    end
    local totwords = #words
    return function(numwords, rotateleft)

        local retstr = ""

        for i = 1 , totwords do
            local index = ( ( (i - 1) + numwords ) % totwords )
            index = rotateleft and index or ((totwords - index) % totwords )
            retstr = retstr .. words[ index + 1] .. " "
        end

        return retstr
    end
end

local rot = rotator(teststr)
print(rot(0,true))
print(rot(3,true))
print(rot(4,true))
print(rot(6,true))
print(rot(1,false))
print(rot(2,false))
print(rot(5,false))
```

The function is created once per string (like an object) and then you can rotate the string left or right. Note when you rotate it to the right it reads the string in the reverse direction of words ( this is akin to a circular list of words and you're traversing it clockwise or anti-clockwise). Here's the program output:

```
D:\Dev\Test>lua5.1 strrotate.lua
hello lua world. wassup there!
wassup there! hello lua world.
there! hello lua world. wassup
lua world. wassup there! hello
there! wassup world. lua hello
wassup world. lua hello there!
hello there! wassup world. lua
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a single gsub and a custom-built pattern.
Try this:

```
s="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

function rotate(s,n)
    local p
    if n>0 then
        p="("..string.rep("%S+",n,"%s+")..")".."(.-)$"
    else
        n=-n
        p="^(.-)%s+".."("..string.rep("%S+",n,"%s+").."%s*)$"
    end
    return (s:gsub(p,"%2 %1"))
end

print('',s)
for i=-5,5 do
    print(i,rotate(s,i))
end
```

You need to decide what to do with whitespace. The code above preserves the whitespace in the rotated words but not around them.